# replace character according to its byte r

Tags: stringr, stringi

I have vector (x) of countries, one of the countries is Cote d'Ivoire

x <- c("c\u00f4te", "côte")
I investigate x I realized that the both cote are not the same

> showNonASCII(x)
>   1: cte
>   2: cte
>   iconv(x, to="ASCII//TRANSLIT")
>   [1] "cA?te" "cote" 
>   Encoding(x)
>   [1] "UTF-8"  "latin1"

I would like to unify  to  so both x are latin1 and equal to each other.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this problem does not arise when used in Mac-OS (with R 3.5.0 MacOS High Sierra v 10.13.6).

```
x <- c("c\u00f4te", "côte")

# check if both are equal
x[1] == x[2]

[1] TRUE

# try to extract the word, if they are different only one should be returned
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(x, "côte")

[[1]]
[1] "côte"

[[2]]
[1] "côte"
```

The problem might be related to different encoding systems used in Windows.